# Detect infinite fraction in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

Infinite fraction: 1/3, 2/3, pie, etc.

Non-infinite fractions: 1/2, 1/5, 1/10, etc.

How can I detect when a a number is an infinitely fraction?

Comment: That's a [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) problem, not a programming question.

Comment: I think you can reduce the fraction and check the factors of the denominator.

Comment: Try checking the continued fraction array representation of the fraction https://github.com/infusion/Fraction.js/#array-tocontinued

Comment: Mathematically speaking, even integers have a repeating decimal part of `0`.

Comment: [How to check if the number after decimal point of the result of a division goes to infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3410237/how-to-check-if-the-number-after-decimal-point-of-the-result-of-a-division-goes)

Comment: [Detecting that a fraction is a repeating decimal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197478/detecting-that-a-fraction-is-a-repeating-decimal)

Comment: Is this a numeric value? Or do you have a string like `"1/3"` and want to examine whether it represents an infinitely recurring decimal fraction?

Comment: @VLAZ
I have it as a string, but if this can be done from the resulting number it would be good as well

Comment: I agree with others that this isn't a programming question, but the answer is quite simple. In base 10, any fraction where the denominator (i.e., the number below the line) is equal a power of 2 times a power of 5 (i.e., 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 16, 20, ...) will have a finite decimal representation. All other fractions are infinitely recurring when expressed as decimals. In base *b*, any number with a prime factor not among the prime factors of *b* will have an infinitely recurring *b*-ary representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.

Carefully following the wisdom laid out in this [question on math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197478/detecting-that-a-fraction-is-a-repeating-decimal), I think the following should do the trick for an [irreducible fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction#Simplifying_(reducing)_fractions):

```js
function* primeFactors(n) {
  let divisor = 2;

  while (n >= 2) {
    if (n % divisor == 0) {
      yield divisor;
      n = n / divisor;
    } else {
      divisor++;
    }
  }
}

const isRepeating = (n, d) => {
  const fn = n % d;
  if (fn === 0) {
    return false;
  }
  return !Array.from(primeFactors(d)).every(v => v === 2 || v === 5)
}
```

So, how to reduce a fraction? If you factorize the numerator and the denominator, you can figure out which factors they have in common, then divide both numerator and denominator by these common factors. Here's one way of doing this:

```js
const counts = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const currentCount = acc.get(curr) ?? 0;
    acc.set(curr, currentCount + 1)
    return acc;
  }, new Map())
}

const reduceFraction = (n, d) => {
  const fn = Array.from(primeFactors(n));
  const fd = Array.from(primeFactors(d));
  const countsFn = counts(fn);
  const countsFd = counts(fd);

  let rn = n;
  let rd = d;

  countsFn.forEach((count, factor) => {
    const fdCount = countsFd.get(factor) ?? 0;
    const c = Math.min(fdCount, count);
    for (let i = 0; i < c; ++i) {
      rn /= factor;
      rd /= factor;
    }
  })

  return { n: rn, d: rd }
}
```

So, putting this all together:

```js
function* primeFactors(n) {
  let divisor = 2;
  while (n >= 2) {
    if (n % divisor === 0) {
      yield divisor;
      n = n / divisor;
    } else {
      divisor++;
    }
  }
}
const counts = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    var _a;
    const currentCount = acc.get(curr) ?? 0;
    acc.set(curr, currentCount + 1);
    return acc;
  }, new Map());
};
const reduceFraction = (n, d) => {
  const fn = Array.from(primeFactors(n));
  const fd = Array.from(primeFactors(d));
  const countsFn = counts(fn);
  const countsFd = counts(fd);
  let rn = n;
  let rd = d;
  countsFn.forEach((count, factor) => {
    var _a;
    const fdCount = countsFd.get(factor) ?? 0;
    const c = Math.min(fdCount, count);
    for (let i = 0; i < c; ++i) {
      rn /= factor;
      rd /= factor;
    }
  });
  return {
    n: rn,
    d: rd
  };
};
const isRepeating = (num, den) => {
  const {
    n,
    d
  } = reduceFraction(num, den);
  const fn = n % d;
  if (fn === 0) {
    return false;
  }
  return !Array.from(primeFactors(d)).every(v => v === 2 || v === 5);
};

console.log(isRepeating(4, 3))
console.log(isRepeating(1, 140))
console.log(isRepeating(1, 2))
console.log(isRepeating(2, 50))
console.log(isRepeating(3, 15))
```

However, be aware that sometimes (due to floating-point stuff), JS might not agree.

```js
const a = 0.1;
let t = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  t += a;
}
console.log(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the maximum length of 32-bit float number after-comma section. Then by getting the number devided, split the number by '.' and get the after-comma period length. if it is the same or length - 1, it is probably infinite fraction

Answer (score -4):

You can use isFinite() function provided by JavaScript.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question,
I mean find infinite fractions, like 0.333333333333333333333333.
Your answer is incorrect.